# number of distinct object types in a list

Tags: c#, list, counting

I am using C#, Silverlight, Visual Studio for Windows Phone 7.

I currently have a List that contains the generic UIElement, and I can put things like TextBlock or Grid or StackPanel into the List.

For example:

```
List<UIElement> UIList= new List<UIelement>();
UIList.Add(someUIObject as UIElement);
```

My question is, is there an efficient way to count the number of object types in my list? For example, if there are 8 TextBlocks and 4 Grids, I would like to know that there are 2 object types in the List. Or if there is 1 TextBlock, 1 Grid, and 1 StackPanel, I would like to know that there are 3 types of objects.

I'm looking for something that is better than O(n^2) performance. My current solution compares each element type to the rest of the element types in the List, something similar to BubbleSort.

Comment: Side note: you don't need the `as UIElement` there, casts to base types are done implictly.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of objects of specific type or the number of different types in the list? And how would your quadratic solution look like? Or the number of objects for each type? Maybe an example would help.

Comment: You can derive from List<> a new class and overload the Add* and Remove* methods so that you maintain a dictionary of types. The point is that, if you have more than one level of inheritance, you'll need to traverse all the hierarchy type for each object added to the list. Higher level counts won't match the sum of lower level counts.

Comment: @svick Ah, good to know about the implicit casting, thank you. I want to count the specific number of types. For example, maybe there are 8 TextBlocks and 4 Grids, so I would want to know that there are 2 types of objects. I'll update the question to clarify this. 

The quadratic solution I was thinking would end up comparing the types of each element to the types of all other elements, kind of BubbleSort-ish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the number of different types in the collection, I would use LINQ to first select the type of each object, then took only distinct types and counted those:

```
int numberOfTypes = UIList.Select(x => x.GetType()).Distinct().Count();
```

All of this will be O(n), because `Distinct()` uses a hash table.

Comment: Oh nice! I didn't know about the Distinct() method. I will give this a try. Thank you :)

Comment: Tried it and it works beautifully. This is exactly what I was looking for! I especially appreciate the simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

try out

```
var loader = loaders.OfType<Elementtype>().Count();
```

Comment: the question was " is there an efficient way to count the number of object types in my list? Something that is better than O(n^2) performance. "

Comment: @Freeman - but this is the easy way to get the element count of specific type that waht i want to show dont want to show count method...

Comment: no one asked about an easy way of counting, the question was about a better count algorythm.

Comment: @Freeman - than you should comment same on Dimitrov answer...which pointing same..

Comment: I upvote the answer => it provides an `O(n)` solution which is better than the `O(n^2)` asked by the OP. It doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: very well, my bad, rectified.

Comment: Thanks Pranay. I updated the question to specify that I'm interested in the number of object types, not the number of a specific type.

Answer (score 3):

```
var types = UIList.GroupBy(ui => ui.GetType())
        .Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use [the overload of `GroupBy()` that takes result selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx), instead of the `Select()`?

Comment: Thanks L.B.  I think your answer is close to what I'm looking for. I would probably just add a .Count() to the end so I get a value for the number of types. Let me try it and see.

Answer (score 2):

The best you could get is `O(n)` complexity by looping through the elements of the list. You could also use LINQ:

```
int numberOfTextBoxes = UIList.OfType<TextBox>().Count();
```

Comment: Thanks Darin. I updated the question to clarify that I'm interested in the number of types, not the number of a specific type. So I'm not looking to see that there are 8 TextBlocks and 4 Grids, but that I have 2 different types of objects in the List.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question in the following way: you want to count each type in the collection.

Then you can use LINQs `GroupBy` and for example a `Dictionary<String, Int32>`, where the key is the name of the type and the value is the number of occurences of that type in the list:

```
Dictionary<String, Int32> typeCounts = UIList
    .GroupBy(c => c.GetType().FullName)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

If you instead just want to know how many different types are in the list, you could simply use above dictionary's `Count` property or:

```
int diffTypeCount = UIList.GroupBy(c => c.GetType().FullName).Count();
```

or if you are interested in a short **and** efficient approach, you might want to use the `ConcurrentDictionary` with it's [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675.aspx) method:

```
var typeCounts = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<String, Int32>();
foreach (var c in UIList)
{
    typeCounts.AddOrUpdate(c.GetType().FullName, 1, (typeName, count) => count + 1); 
}
int diffTypeCount = typeCounts.Count;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I updated the question to specify that I'm interested in the number of object types, not the number of objects of a specific type.

Comment: Why are you grouping by `FullName` and not directly by the `Type`?

Comment: @svick: Because i don't know the implementation of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in `System.Type`, but it's well-known  for `System.String` ;)